# Ubuntu 16.04 unexplained swap usage

Tags: swap

I fail to understand why my `swap` is getting full on my Ubuntu 16.04 although I have plenty of available memory:

[image]

[image]

When looking at what processes are actually using `swap` :

```
************************************
Swap's process in count 1 
systemd : 1 : VmSwap:        520 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 21002 : VmSwap:        3324 kB
systemd-journal : 2326 : VmSwap:        2356 kB
lvmetad : 2353 : VmSwap:           8 kB
systemd-udevd : 2358 : VmSwap:      3052 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 25162 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 28879 : VmSwap:        176 kB
bash : 30064 : VmSwap:      1460 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 34334 : VmSwap:        180 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 36841 : VmSwap:        3708 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 36847 : VmSwap:        2976 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39489 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39491 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39493 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39494 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/opt/otrs/bin/c : 39496 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39497 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39498 : VmSwap:        176 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 43266 : VmSwap:        4320 kB
sshd : 43477 : VmSwap:        12 kB
sshd : 43555 : VmSwap:        72 kB
bash : 43556 : VmSwap:      1328 kB
bash : 43577 : VmSwap:       212 kB
ldapsearch : 43623 : VmSwap:         672 kB
ldapsearch : 43625 : VmSwap:         648 kB
ldapsearch : 43741 : VmSwap:         636 kB
sshd : 44183 : VmSwap:        12 kB
sshd : 44257 : VmSwap:        48 kB
bash : 44258 : VmSwap:      1044 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 44373 : VmSwap:        5912 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 45169 : VmSwap:        4344 kB
lxcfs : 4987 : VmSwap:      2208 kB
vmtoolsd : 4991 : VmSwap:      27168 kB
cron : 5044 : VmSwap:        136 kB
snapd : 5053 : VmSwap:      4728 kB
systemd-logind : 5055 : VmSwap:       48 kB
accounts-daemon : 5057 : VmSwap:          52 kB
dbus-daemon : 5059 : VmSwap:           4 kB
rsyslogd : 5082 : VmSwap:         44 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 50961 : VmSwap:        4348 kB
sshd : 5141 : VmSwap:        588 kB
polkitd : 5149 : VmSwap:           4 kB
mysqld : 5153 : VmSwap:   675748 kB
mdadm : 5162 : VmSwap:         4 kB
master : 5459 : VmSwap:      360 kB
qmgr : 5462 : VmSwap:         68 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 57161 : VmSwap:        4324 kB
systemd : 57265 : VmSwap:        896 kB
(sd-pam) : 57274 : VmSwap:       572 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 57937 : VmSwap:       56068 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 8414 : VmSwap:         176 kB
************************************
Swap's process in count 2 
systemd : 1 : VmSwap:        520 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 21002 : VmSwap:        3324 kB
systemd-journal : 2326 : VmSwap:        2356 kB
lvmetad : 2353 : VmSwap:           8 kB
systemd-udevd : 2358 : VmSwap:      3052 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 25162 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 28879 : VmSwap:        176 kB
bash : 30064 : VmSwap:      1460 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 34334 : VmSwap:        180 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 36841 : VmSwap:        3708 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 36847 : VmSwap:        2976 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39489 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39491 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39493 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39494 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39496 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39497 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39498 : VmSwap:        176 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 43266 : VmSwap:        4320 kB
sshd : 43477 : VmSwap:        12 kB
sshd : 43555 : VmSwap:        72 kB
bash : 43556 : VmSwap:      1328 kB
bash : 43577 : VmSwap:       212 kB
ldapsearch : 43623 : VmSwap:         672 kB
ldapsearch : 43625 : VmSwap:         648 kB
ldapsearch : 43741 : VmSwap:         636 kB
sshd : 44183 : VmSwap:        12 kB
sshd : 44257 : VmSwap:        48 kB
bash : 44258 : VmSwap:      1044 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 44373 : VmSwap:        5912 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 45169 : VmSwap:        4344 kB
lxcfs : 4987 : VmSwap:      2208 kB
vmtoolsd : 4991 : VmSwap:      27168 kB
cron : 5044 : VmSwap:        136 kB
snapd : 5053 : VmSwap:      4728 kB
systemd-logind : 5055 : VmSwap:       48 kB
accounts-daemon : 5057 : VmSwap:          52 kB
dbus-daemon : 5059 : VmSwap:           4 kB
rsyslogd : 5082 : VmSwap:         44 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 50961 : VmSwap:        4348 kB
sshd : 5141 : VmSwap:        588 kB
polkitd : 5149 : VmSwap:           4 kB
mysqld : 5153 : VmSwap:   675748 kB
mdadm : 5162 : VmSwap:         4 kB
master : 5459 : VmSwap:      360 kB
qmgr : 5462 : VmSwap:         68 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 57161 : VmSwap:        4324 kB
systemd : 57265 : VmSwap:        896 kB
(sd-pam) : 57274 : VmSwap:       572 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 57937 : VmSwap:       56068 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 8414 : VmSwap:         176 kB
************************************
Swap's process in count 3 
systemd : 1 : VmSwap:        520 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 21002 : VmSwap:        3324 kB
systemd-journal : 2326 : VmSwap:        2356 kB
lvmetad : 2353 : VmSwap:           8 kB
systemd-udevd : 2358 : VmSwap:      3052 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 25162 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 28879 : VmSwap:        176 kB
bash : 30064 : VmSwap:      1460 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 34334 : VmSwap:        180 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39489 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39491 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39493 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39494 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39496 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39497 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39498 : VmSwap:        176 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 43266 : VmSwap:        4320 kB
sshd : 43477 : VmSwap:        12 kB
sshd : 43555 : VmSwap:        72 kB
bash : 43556 : VmSwap:      1328 kB
bash : 43577 : VmSwap:       212 kB
ldapsearch : 43623 : VmSwap:         672 kB
ldapsearch : 43625 : VmSwap:         648 kB
ldapsearch : 43741 : VmSwap:         636 kB
sshd : 44183 : VmSwap:        12 kB
sshd : 44257 : VmSwap:        48 kB
bash : 44258 : VmSwap:      1044 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 44373 : VmSwap:        5912 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 45169 : VmSwap:        4344 kB
lxcfs : 4987 : VmSwap:      2208 kB
vmtoolsd : 4991 : VmSwap:      27168 kB
cron : 5044 : VmSwap:        136 kB
snapd : 5053 : VmSwap:      4728 kB
systemd-logind : 5055 : VmSwap:       48 kB
accounts-daemon : 5057 : VmSwap:          52 kB
dbus-daemon : 5059 : VmSwap:           4 kB
rsyslogd : 5082 : VmSwap:         44 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 50961 : VmSwap:        4348 kB
sshd : 5141 : VmSwap:        588 kB
polkitd : 5149 : VmSwap:           4 kB
mysqld : 5153 : VmSwap:   675748 kB
mdadm : 5162 : VmSwap:         4 kB
master : 5459 : VmSwap:      360 kB
qmgr : 5462 : VmSwap:         68 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 57161 : VmSwap:        4324 kB
systemd : 57265 : VmSwap:        896 kB
(sd-pam) : 57274 : VmSwap:       572 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 57937 : VmSwap:       56068 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 8414 : VmSwap:         176 kB
************************************
Swap's process in count 4 
systemd : 1 : VmSwap:        520 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 21002 : VmSwap:        3324 kB
systemd-journal : 2326 : VmSwap:        2356 kB
lvmetad : 2353 : VmSwap:           8 kB
systemd-udevd : 2358 : VmSwap:      3052 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 25162 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 28879 : VmSwap:        176 kB
bash : 30064 : VmSwap:      1460 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 34334 : VmSwap:        180 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39489 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39491 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39493 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39494 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39496 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39497 : VmSwap:        176 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 39498 : VmSwap:        176 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 43266 : VmSwap:        4320 kB
sshd : 43477 : VmSwap:        12 kB
sshd : 43555 : VmSwap:        72 kB
bash : 43556 : VmSwap:      1328 kB
bash : 43577 : VmSwap:       212 kB
ldapsearch : 43623 : VmSwap:         672 kB
ldapsearch : 43625 : VmSwap:         648 kB
ldapsearch : 43741 : VmSwap:         636 kB
sshd : 44183 : VmSwap:        12 kB
sshd : 44257 : VmSwap:        48 kB
bash : 44258 : VmSwap:      1044 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 44373 : VmSwap:        5912 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 45169 : VmSwap:        4344 kB
lxcfs : 4987 : VmSwap:      2208 kB
vmtoolsd : 4991 : VmSwap:      27168 kB
cron : 5044 : VmSwap:        136 kB
snapd : 5053 : VmSwap:      4728 kB
systemd-logind : 5055 : VmSwap:       48 kB
accounts-daemon : 5057 : VmSwap:          52 kB
dbus-daemon : 5059 : VmSwap:           4 kB
rsyslogd : 5082 : VmSwap:         44 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 50961 : VmSwap:        4348 kB
sshd : 5141 : VmSwap:        588 kB
polkitd : 5149 : VmSwap:           4 kB
mysqld : 5153 : VmSwap:   675748 kB
mdadm : 5162 : VmSwap:         4 kB
master : 5459 : VmSwap:      360 kB
qmgr : 5462 : VmSwap:         68 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 57161 : VmSwap:        4324 kB
systemd : 57265 : VmSwap:        896 kB
(sd-pam) : 57274 : VmSwap:       572 kB
otrs.Daemon.pl : 57937 : VmSwap:       56068 kB
/usr/sbin/apach : 8414 : VmSwap:         176 kB
```

Can anyone please explain my why it is happening? Can a process by itself swap even if there is plenty available memory?

EDIT:

Running `vmstat` shows 0 for both `si` an `so`(note that the output is truncated and I have run the command for a fair amount of time):

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, processes can be swapped even when there's memory available. This is controlled by the virtual memory `swappiness` value which, as you show, is set to 60 on your system (the default on many installations). The [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/s-memory-tunables) has a nice explanation (this is applicable to any Linux):

> **swappiness**
>
> A value from 0 to 100 which controls the degree to which the system
>   favors anonymous memory or the page cache. A high value improves
>   file-system performance, while aggressively swapping less active
>   processes out of physical memory. A low value avoids swapping
>   processes out of memory, which usually decreases latency, at the cost
>   of I/O performance. The default value is 60.
>
> A low swappiness value is recommended for database workloads. For example, for Oracle databases, Red Hat recommends a swappiness value of 10.

If you want to set it to a lower value, 10 for example, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add a line like this:

```
vm.swappiness=10
```

Note that for newer versions of `systemd`, you need to edit/create files in `/etc/sysctl.d/` instead. As explained in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sysctl#Configuration):

> Note: From version 207 and 21x, systemd only applies settings from `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf` and `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf`. If you had customized `/etc/sysctl.conf`, you need to rename it as `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf`. If you had e.g. `/etc/sysctl.d/foo`, you need to rename it to `/etc/sysctl.d/foo.conf`.

However, bear in mind that swapping is not necessarily a problem. It all depends on what your machine is doing. There is a [nice and detailed answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/184221/85695) addressing this issue on Ask Ubuntu, which I suggest you read. Basically, unless your machine feels sluggish, let it be.

Further reading:

- [Ubuntu SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

Comment: thank you for such a great answer! Might it be that my swap size is not enough comparing to available RAM?

Comment: @yesOrMaybeWhatever I don't see why. Is this actually a problem? Is your system slow and unresponsive?

Comment: we have an application running on it (OTRS) and it became slow in responding but it turned out that the LDAP Server used for lookups was unavailable - after correcting it, the application started to behave normal but their support claims that we should have 60% free space in swap but sa you mentioned, when the system decides itself when to swap how can we even control it ?

Comment: @yesOrMaybeWhatever you can control it by setting the vm.swappiness value to something lower for les aggressive swapping. I don't see why you would need to have X% free swap though. That sounds weird. The important point here is that swap != bad. In fact, often swap = good! So unless you are really seeing swap causing a problem, leave it as it is. I would lower it for a personal system, but not for a server.